# Selectors in custom UIViewController not calling functions within class

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on a simple game in my free time which has two view controllers: the default ViewController, and GameViewController. I have it setup so that GameViewController is a subview of a UIView within my ViewController, which I did so that I could customize transitions between my main menu and the actual game (I would love to find some more efficient ways of doing this in the future!)

The problem I'm currently having, is that selectors which I declare in my GameViewController class won't call functions within the GameViewController class, *but,* selectors do call functions within my ViewController class just fine. For example, here's some code in my ViewController class and GameViewController classes:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@objc func myFunc() {
     print("Some output to show that the ViewController function is working")
     }
}

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     let myButton = UIButton()
     myButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
     myButton.backgroundColor = .green

     // This works fine. The function in ViewController is called, and I get some output in the console
     myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.myFunc), for:.touchUpInside)

     // This does NOT work. No output is shown, therefore the function in GameViewController never got called
     myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.myFunc2), for:.touchUpInside)

     view.addSubview(myButton)
}

@objc func myFunc2() {
     print("Some different output to show that the GameViewController function is working")
     }
}
```

I also tried, just in case there was some problem with my button, to use Notifications to call my function. Since I knew my function in ViewController was working, I posted a notification from that function and added an observer to my GameViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@objc func myFunc() {
     print("Some output to show that the ViewController function is working")
     NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .myNotification, object: nil)
     }
}

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     let myButton = UIButton()
     myButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
     myButton.backgroundColor = .green

     myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.myFunc), for:.touchUpInside)

     view.addSubview(myButton)

     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.myFunc2(notification:)), name: .myNotification, object: nil)
}

@objc func myFunc2(notification: NSNotification) {
     print("Some different output to show that the GameViewController function is working")
     }
}

extension Notification.Name {
     static let myNotification = Notification.Name("myNotification")
}
```

And even using Notifications, the function was called in ViewController, the notification was (supposedly) posted, and *still* my GameViewController function never got called.

I've used breakpoints to make sure 100% that my observer is being called *before* the notification is posted, and I've called myFunc2 in GameViewController's viewDidLoad and got output, so I really can't understand why I'm having so much trouble.

Any insights help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I made it work.

It turns out that, and I'm honestly not 100% sure this is totally accurate, because I was using a convenience init (something I forgot to mention in the OP), "self" ended up pointing to the current instance of ViewController and so when I tried to call "self.myFunc2," it was actually trying to call "ViewController.myFunc2" which obviously didn't exist.

It doesn't make sense to my why it wasn't outright crashing when it tried to call a nonexistent function, and I don't really get why "self" wasn't working as intended, but I guess that's a case closed.